# Problem positioning graphics in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html

I have a problem with positioning graphics in Chrome and Safari. My code works fine in IE and Firefox.

A typical line of code is

```
<Div Style='{position:absolute; left:326px;top: 268px;}'>
    <A Href='Venues.asp?id=2'>Image code</A>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not code. This is HTML markup. And please explain what _exactly_ doesn't work.

Comment: Side note: the curly braces aren't supported in style are they? `style="{property: name;}"` should be `style="property: name;"`

Answer (score 1):

Kill the curly braces. It should just be `style="position:absolute; left:326px; top:268px;"`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari are based on Webkit. Add this to the bottom of you stylesheet and put the class you want to adjust in here.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
.class {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove curly braces from your inline style. Also no need to capitalize `<a>` and `<div>` tags. Your code should look like

```
<div Style='position:absolute; left:326px;top: 268px'><a Href='Venues.asp?id=2'>Image code</a></div>
```